# for-loop left after one iteration

Tags: c

I'm encountering this problem and I don't get why. I used the exact same loop before to test it (without inside code) and it worked. I'm not a programming newbie (though c newbie), but now I definitely feel like one. I replaced length with a hard coded number, doesn't change anything. jobStatus() also only uses a for-loop which works fine. Help is appreciated!

PS: Don't mind the if / else-if part. This was just a desperation move because I cant find the problem, I know that I don't need the last else if etc.

thanks in advance

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

short jobs[] = {6,13,7,3,4,9,10,11};
short table[13][10];
short Q,i,j,k,diff;
short sum;

void jobStatus(short a){
printf("Jobstatus:");
for(i=0;i<a;i++){
    printf(" %i",jobs[i]);
} printf("\n");
}

int main(){
// berechne Anzahl der Jobs
short length = sizeof(jobs)/2;
printf("Jobs: %i\n", length);

/* für alle Quanten Q
for(Q=0;Q<13;Q++){
    // schreibe das jeweilige Quantum in die erste Spalte jeder Zeile
    table[Q][0]=(Q+1);  
     gehe jeden Job durch*/

        for(i=0;i<length;i++){
            printf("Current Job: %i\n", i);
            /* falls der aktuelle job i bereits erledigt ist   überspringe ihn
            if(jobs[i]==0){
                i++;
            }*/
            diff=jobs[i]-(Q+1);
            if(diff>0){
                jobs[i]=diff;
                jobStatus(length);
                table[Q][i+1]=diff;
            } else if(diff==0){
                jobs[i]=0;
            } else if(diff<0){
                diff=diff*(-1);
                jobs[i]=0;
                table[Q][i+1]+=diff;
            }   
        }   

printf("#  Q P1 P2 P3 P4 P5 P6 P7 P8 Avg.Time\n");
printf("#------------------------------------\n");
for(Q=0;Q<13;Q++){
    for(i=0;i<8;i++){
        printf(" %i", table[Q][i]);     
    }
    printf("\n");
}
return 0;
```

}

This is the output:

Jobs: 8 // Indicates that length should be set to 8

Jobstatus: 5 13 7 3 4 9 10 11

### Q P1 P2 P3 P4 P5 P6 P7 P8 Avg.Time

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have only a global variable `i` which is used in both for loops (inside `jobstatus` and in your `main`). Thus once you call `jobstatus(length);` within your main loop the content of the variable will be changed and afterwards the loop terminates (because `i` was then set to `length`).

Answer (score 3):

You are using global variable i. It is changes inside jobStatus and for-loop in main.
Try to use local inside main()

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Howard, but I think that sizeof(jobs) it's wrong. You should write something like `(sizeof (jobs))/(sizeof (jobs[0]))` or instead use count() function.

Comment: well it worked, edited it though ;) what does (sizeof (jobs))/(sizeof (jobs[0])) actually do? thx

Comment: It's only to get the length of your array. This is like a basket full of apples hehe. Assuming that the basket has no weight and that all the apples together weight 100 grams, if you know the weight of a single apple, you how many apples you have (100/5) xD. Sorry about that example, but I think is quite clarifying ;).